# RGB-led cycle colours of the rainbow arduino

Tags: arduino, rgb

I am fairly new to programming and have bought an arduino uno for practice. I want to make an RGB-led light up circling the colours of the rainbow (cyan - blue - magenta etc..)
There is some sort of logical problem with my code. The first circle is fine, it goes through the colors nicely. It is in the second circle that the red color starts acting up and flashes 9 times when it is not supposed to in the "blue segment of the circle".

My whole code is like this:

```
int BLUEARR[] = {1,1,1,0,0,0};
int GREENARR[] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1};
int REDARR[] = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0};

int red, green, blue;

int RedPin = 9;
int GreenPin = 10;
int BluePin = 11;

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
  for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
    int k = (i+1)%6;
    for (int j=0; j<256; j++) {
      blue = BLUEARR[i]*255+(BLUEARR[k] - BLUEARR[i])*j;
      red = REDARR[i]*255+(REDARR[k]  - REDARR[i])*j;
      green = GREENARR[i]*255+(GREENARR[k] - GREENARR[i])*j;

      analogWrite (RedPin, red);
      analogWrite (GreenPin, green);
      analogWrite (BluePin, blue);
      delay(20);
    }
  }
}
```

anyone knows? Kind regards.

Comment: So, even weirder: if i add an array, say ARR[] = {0,1,0,1,0,1}, attach it to some pin i dont use and then add it to the main loop the flashing of the red LED stops and it acts ALMOST as i want it to. it is just that the green light makes a jump so it looks like it looses the connection and then appear again in the beginning of the loop. But the blue light is constant and the red light works aswell..

Comment: I FIXED IT! The foorloop must not go past 5, so i should be less than 6, ofcourse!